# Ngrx Effects: Conditionally return action inside switchMap instead of http response

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm currently working in an Angular 5 app that is going to use some cache strategies with ngrx-store, for allowing users to view an item and go back to the main list without having to make the request again.

I'm using an Effect to request data and using a reducer to update my global state based on my htp response. As you can see, for success the RequestPartnersSuccess action is triggered, and for errors the RequestPartnersFail is triggered.

The property 'internalAppDynamic.searchPartners.recoverLatest' from my global state indicates if I should recover my list from cache, and in this case the effect should return a method inside this 'if' statement and finishes my stream.

```
@Effect()
  loadPartners$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(SearchPartnersActions.REQUEST_PARTNERS)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store$, (action, state) => {
      action = Object.assign(action, {recoverLatest: state.internalAppDynamic.searchPartners.recoverLatest})
      return action
    })
    .pipe(switchMap((action: any) => {
      if (action.recoverLatest) {
        return new SearchPartnersActions.RequestPartnersRecoverCache()
      }
      return this.internalPartnersService.getPartners(action.payload).pipe(
        map(partners => new SearchPartnersActions.RequestPartnersSuccess(partners)),
        catchError(error => of(new SearchPartnersActions.RequestPartnersFail(error)))
      )
    }))
```

And this is the getPartners() function from my service:

```
getPartners (body): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
    .post(this._baseUrl + 'internal-app/get-partners', body, this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(catchError((error: any) => this.errorHandler(error)))
  }
```

The thing is that I couldn't find a way to achieve this result. I'm new to rxjs and Observables, and I think the switchMap operator expects another kind of return instead of a new instance of my SearchPartnersActions.RequestPartnersRecoverCache() class.

What could I do to achieve the desired result? Could someone explain to me better what is expected from this stream of Observables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to achieve the desired behavior by creating an auxiliary observable just to be able to pass my action inside the stream, like this:

```
  auxObservable () {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      observer.next()
    })
  }

  @Effect()
  loadPartners$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(SearchPartnersActions.REQUEST_PARTNERS)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store$, (action, state) => {
      action = Object.assign(action, {recoverLatest: state.internalAppDynamic.searchPartners.recoverLatest})
      return action
    })
    .pipe(switchMap((action: any) => {
      if (action.recoverLatest) {
        return this.auxObservable().pipe(
          map(res => new SearchPartnersActions.RequestPartnersRecoverCache())
        )
      }
      return this.internalPartnersService.getPartners(action.payload).pipe(
        map(partners => new SearchPartnersActions.RequestPartnersSuccess(partners)),
        catchError(error => of(new SearchPartnersActions.RequestPartnersFail(error)))
      )
    }))
```

If you need to pass your action object inside the stream to use it's type or payload for something else, you should pass it as a auxObservable parameter, like this:

```
  auxObservable (action) {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      observer.next(action)
    })
  }

  @Effect()
  loadPartners$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(SearchPartnersActions.REQUEST_PARTNERS)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store$, (action, state) => {
      action = Object.assign(action, {recoverLatest: state.internalAppDynamic.searchPartners.recoverLatest})
      return action
    })
    .pipe(switchMap((action: any) => {
      if (action.recoverLatest) {
        return this.auxObservable(action).pipe(
          map(res => new SearchPartnersActions.RequestPartnersRecoverCache())
        )
      }
      return this.internalPartnersService.getPartners(action.payload).pipe(
        map(partners => new SearchPartnersActions.RequestPartnersSuccess(partners)),
        catchError(error => of(new SearchPartnersActions.RequestPartnersFail(error)))
      )
    }))
```

I think someone might need this technique in the future, so I'm sharing my solution =)

If someone can think about a better way to intercept the default stream behavior if a condition is met and trigger a diferent reducer case, please share it with us!

Update:

As Alexander pointed out, the auxObservable is not necessary and it's possible to just return of(new SearchPartnersActions.RequestPartnersRecoverCache()), making sure you imported the 'of' operator from rxjs.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need auxObservable and pipes for it. Just do `return Observable.of(new WhateverObject())`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is going to help me. But how this 'of' operator works inside the stream? In my solution, by creating the observer with a function, I am able to trigger multiple next() functions and even controll my stream by using observer.complete. In the 'of' operator it just passes 'new WhateverObject' into the stream, like the observer.next() from Observer.create?

Comment: I've just looked in the rxjs api, and the 'of' method is exactly the same as 'create', passing all arguments in sequence inside next() and them emiting a .complete. So unless you need aditional logic between your next() functions, it's best to use Observable.of(val1, val2, val3,...) instead of creating an Observable from a function. Thanks again, Alexander!

Comment: You got it all right. Well done! Please update your answer to reflect this, cause others not so familiar with rx could be teached to use unnecessary constructs.

Comment: Alexander, I've just tried to modify my code using return Observable.of(), but in this @Effect situation in wich it's a stream that expects values to be passed into it via the pipe operator, it seems that the stream expects an iterable result so it can be mapped and passed  into the pipe. So just using return Observable.of() without piping and mapping it won't work =/

Comment: I see. I'm not used to using pies yet, drifted to c# world for a while. You're right but it still should be possible to get around this. I'll take a look.

Comment: Yes, I've got a feeling that there's a better way to achieve this. Well, for now I'm going to stick with my workaround and as soon as I discover a better solution I'll update my code. Thanks again for your attention, Alexander!

Comment: Found it. All you need to do is to use `of` operator just like any other in the pipe: `something.pipe(switchMap(s => of(new SomeObject())))`, and of course import `of` operator: `import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';`

Comment: Omg, I was using this in my effect the whole time in the error handler! Kkkkkkk thank you very much for your time, my friend!